# C++ Should I overwrite copy constructor in derived class

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, c++11

I have base class with custom copy constructor that takes care of alocated memory.
I also have class dervied from that base. That derived class is not doing anything more with memory.

How should copy constructor look in dervied class?
How about overwriting swap, move and assign?

Comment: Disregard my previous answer, it's incorrect for compiler-generated copy constructors.

Comment: Note that in C++(03) constructors are *not* inherited.  In each subclass, you're starting from zero.

Comment: I like to say that inheritance doesn't apply to constructors because they logically belong to the class, not the object (contrary to destructors).

Comment: @JohnDibling How's this important for copy-constructors? The copy-ctor of the base class *will* be called from the implicitly-defined copy-ctor of the derived class.

Comment: @DyP:  Reading the question, I suspected it was possible that the OP did not realize that he had to explicitly call the base class' copy constructor in the derived class' initialization list.  I was just pointing this out.

Comment: @JohnDibling Well, yes, that makes sense for user-defined ctors.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't have to do anything other than maybe for `swap`. A base class is like a data member in this respect, the compiler-generated copy constructor and assignment (and moves if applicable) include it.

`swap` is different because there's no compiler-generated `swap`, just the default implementation in namespace `std` and then whatever specialization or ADL-overload the programmer defines for a user-defined type.

So if there's already a function that looks like:

```
namespace foo {
    void swap(Base &lhs, Base &rhs) {
        lhs.swap(rhs); // or maybe the gory details are in this function
    }
}
```

and you do nothing, and some user calls it like:

```
foo::swap(derived1, derived2);
```

then the base parts will be swapped and the derived parts won't, which is pretty bad.

*Users shouldn't call swap like that*, but you know what users are like. It might look especially tempting to the user if `Base` and `Derived` are in the same namespace, and they just assume it'll all work. So you might want to ensure that there's an overload for `Derived` in order to stop them, if you think your users are (or your own code base is) unprincipled in how it calls `swap`.

Users should call `swap` like:

```
using std::swap;
swap(base1, base2);
swap(derived1, derived2);
```

That will call `foo::swap` when used with `Base` and `std::swap` when called with `Derived`. `std::swap<Derived>` might be inefficient (if `Base` has a swap implemented for efficiency, then `Derived` should too). So you probably want to implement a `swap` for `Derived` for that reason too, but slow isn't as bad as wrong.

That said, you're asking about moves. If `Derived` is efficiently movable then `std::swap<Derived>` isn't bad. Maybe it can be improved on, maybe not, but it should be marginal because three moves is hard to beat.

You and users should also be aware that `swap` does not play nicely with polymorphism (because in general two objects must have the same complete type in order for swapping them to make sense), and implementing it for a base class might cause trouble.

```
Derived d1, d2;
Base &b1 = &d1, &b2 = d2;
swap(b1, d2); // swaps just the base part
swap(b1, b2); // swaps just the base part
```

So firstly, users need to know not to call swap like that. Secondly, you might want to consider whether or not a `Base` with a `swap` is really well-designed as a base class.

Comment: *"Secondly, you might want to consider whether or not a Base with a swap is really well-designed as a base class.*" A good hint. But I think this only applies if the inheritance is public.

Comment: @DyP: yes, and if the inheritance is private then there's no danger of someone calling the wrong `foo::swap` either. Private inheritance isn't polymorphism as far as users of the class are concerned, for most (all?) practical purposes.

Answer (score 1):

There's the so-called rule-of-five (formerly rule-of-three), which says if you have user-defined any of those:

- copy constructor
- move constructor
- destructor
- copy assignment-operator
- move assignment-operator

than you'll probably also want to user-define the other four.

---

On the other hand, there's the [rule-of-zero](https://web.archive.org/web/20151006051620/http://flamingdangerzone.com/cxx11/rule-of-zero/): Instead of defining those five special member functions, you can use resource objects (RAII) that automatically take care of these things.

Whether such an object is a data member or a base class (subobject) of some class `C` doesn't care: The implicitly declared & defined special member functions of `C` provided by the compiler will invoke the special member function of this resource object, which will most probably be sufficient.

*hint:* A more precise answer could be given for a specific example

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "overwrite" a constructor. It's not a term in the C++ vocabulary. You can *override* a function, but only if it's virtual.

Normally you shouldn't do anything special in the constructors of children of any correctly written base class. Let each generation take care of itself.

Comment: @JohnDibling Sure you can *overload* a constructor, just like any other function, within a class.

Comment: Uh, whoops. :)  All I can really say to that.